# Pycharm: Incorrect Project Structure Folder

Tags: pycharm

I am running Pycharm and running multiple projects.

Whenever I open a project, it starts up with the last opened project's folder. I have to go to Settings > Project > Project Structure, Remove the other project's folder under Content Root and change it to the current project.

I am using PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.2, Build #PC-171.4249.47

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but the problem sounds very similar to the old fixed bug caused by [PY-23930](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23930).

Try to remove `ProjectModuleManager` component configuration from `project.default.xml` in the application config directory (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs).

Comment: I believe you still have to edit `project.default.xml`. The new version won't corrupt the file but it also won't restore it to the OK condition.

Comment: I deleted the `ProjectModuleManager` and used the new version and it's all good. Thanks for the help